# Problem in nest query for sorting in aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-aggregation

I need to get a query from Elasticsearch for last registered records in specified area in range of specified serial numbers.
for this reason I mapped my index in this shape:

```
{ "settings": {
"index": {
  "number_of_shards": 5,
  "number_of_replicas": 2
}
},
"mapping": {
"AssetStatus": {
  "properties": {
    "serialnumber": {
      "type": "text",
      "fielddata": true
    },
    "vehiclestate": {
      "type": "text",
      "fielddata": true
    },
    "vehiclegeopoint": {
      "type": "geo-point",
      "fielddata": true
    },
    "vehiclespeed": {
      "type": "number",
      "fielddata": true
    },
    "vehiclefuelpercent": {
      "type": "text",
      "fielddata": true
    },
    "devicebatterypercent": {
      "type": "text",
      "fielddata": true
    },
    "networklatency": {
      "type": "text",
      "fielddata": true
    },
    "satellitescount": {
      "type": "number",
      "fielddata": true
    },
    "createdate": {
      "type": "date",
      "fielddata": true
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

and this query works correctly

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "serialnumber.keyword": "2228187d-b1a5-4e18-82bb-4d12438e0ec0"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "vehiclegeopoint.lat": {
              "gt": "31.287958",
              "lt": "31.295485"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "vehiclegeopoint.lon": {
              "gt": "48.639844",
              "lt": "48.652032"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "sort": [],
  "aggs": {
    "SerialNumberGroups": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "serialnumber.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "tops": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "createdate.keyword": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

whereas my nest query has this error

> Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on
>   POST: /fms2/AssetStatus/_search?typed_keys=true
>
> ## Audit trail of this API call:
>
> - [1] BadResponse: Node: http://localhost:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.1917118
>
>   ## OriginalException: Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: Request failed to execute. Call: Status code 400 from: POST
>
> /fms2/AssetStatus/_search?typed_keys=true. ServerError: Type:
>   parsing_exception Reason: "Unknown key for a VALUE_STRING in [field]."
>
> Request:
>
> force it to be set on the response.>
>
> Response:
>
> ConnectionSettings to force it to be set on the response.>

my nest query is this

```
    var searchResponse =
        Client.Search<AssetStatus>(x => x
            .Index(settings.DefaultIndex)
            .Type("AssetStatus")
            .Query(fq => fq.GeoBoundingBox(c => c.Field(f => f.VehicleGeoPoint).BoundingBox(new GeoLocation(TopLeft.Lat, TopLeft.Lon), new GeoLocation(BottomRight.Lat, BottomRight.Lon))))
            .Query(fq =>
                fq.Bool(b => b.
                Filter(
                    f => f.Match(m => m.Field(g => g.SerialNumber.Suffix("keyword").Equals(sn)))
                )
            ))
            .Aggregations(a => a
                .Terms("group_by_SerialNumber", st => st
                    .Field(o => o.SerialNumber.Suffix("keyword"))
                    .Size(0)
                    .Aggregations(b=> b.TopHits("top_hits", lastRegistered => lastRegistered
                        .Field(bf=> bf.CreateDate.Suffix("keyword"))
                        .Size(1)))
                        ))
                        );
```

This problem is for sorting in aggregation

Comment: Your mapping looks to have a few errors e.g. (1) type is `geo_point` and **not** `geo-point`, (2) `fielddata` is only valid on `text` fields (although I would recommend using `fields` mapping with `keyword` datatype instead of `fielddata`. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in my POCO,  as you can see in my nest query I use uppercase letters for naming my properties. I should use Nest library for using data annotation for elastic's POCO.

```
[ElasticsearchType(Name = "AssetStatus")]
public class AssetStatus
{
    [Text]
    [PropertyName("serialnumber")]
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    [Text]
    [PropertyName("vehiclestate")]
    public string VehicleState { get; set; }
    [GeoPoint]
    [PropertyName("vehiclegeopoint")]
    public GeoPoint VehicleGeoPoint { get; set; }
    [Number]
    [PropertyName("vehiclespeed")]
    public int VehicleSpeed { get; set; }
    [Text]
    [PropertyName("vehiclefuelpercent")]
    public string VehicleFuelPercent { get; set; }
    [Text]
    [PropertyName("devicebatterypercent")]
    public string DeviceBatteryPercent { get; set; }
    [Text]
    [PropertyName("networklatency")]
    public string NetworkLatency { get; set; }
    [Number]
    [PropertyName("satellitescount")]
    public byte SatellitesCount { get; set; }
    [Date]
    [PropertyName("createdate")]
    public string CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```